# D3 plot color scheme issue when using Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js

I’m having a difficult time getting some D3 plots to use a color scheme that I specify. I’m using flask, Twitter Bootstrap, and D3.

To be specific, I’m trying to make a piechart using data from a CSV file (see code below). Even though I specify my own colors for the chart (see the part of the code: “.range(["#FF4A29", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00”]);”) the resulting chart has weird purple and green colors (see below). These same purple and green colors appear in other D3 plots I make on the page.

When I use this javascript code on a non-Bootstrap page, it looks right! I’m guessing something in the Bootstrap CSS is overriding the javascript code? Is there anyway to force my specified colors?

```
<style>

.arc text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  text-anchor: middle;
}

.arc path {
  stroke: #fff;
}

</style>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 500,
    height = 500,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 3;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#FF4A29", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(0);

var labelArc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius + 60)
    .innerRadius(radius - 40);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return d.mentions; });

var svg2 = d3.select("#competitors").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2.3 + "," + height / 2.3 + ")");

d3.csv("static/competitor_mentions.csv", type, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var g = svg2.selectAll(".arc")
      .data(pie(data))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");

  g.append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.company); });

  g.append("text")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + labelArc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.company; });
});

function type(d) {
  d.mentions = +d.mentions;
  return d;
}

</script>
```

[image: Pie chart with weird colors]

Comment: Please check the example code at [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/xEKkXK) of d3.js with bootstrap included i do not find any issue of bootstrap overriding the colors. Please share your code in any code editor to analyze the problem better. Thank You

Comment: Hi Jyoti, thanks for making that page. I'm concerned that it'll be hard to get bootstrap to work with it, but I tried copying the bootstrap CSS. It doesn't seem to be working. What do you think?

Comment: Please share your code in any code editor(like codepen, jsfiddle, etc). I will try to find what went wrong in your code.

Comment: I'm very confused because it works in this jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/slyron/452k3ekt/), but it doesn't work on my machine...

Comment: Debug your code, I am sure you will find the bug by comparing the working and non working copy.